# Android authorization by OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am developing an android native-app from which I want to call the API of a web application
(they give access to their API through OAuth 2.0). As I understand it, *Implicit Grant* 
is the appropriate way of access for my case, and I comprehent (at least I think so) the 
client-side web app flow:

1. Send a GET request to the authorization server
2. Authenticate user with username-password
3. Authorization server sends back a redirect_url that contains the access_token
4. Use the access_token for API calls

From the two options of getting authorization (**1. embedded WebView** or **2. open a web browser window**), I have opted for the latter. So far, I can open the browser with the URL:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(OAUTH_URL+"?client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&response_type=token&redirect_uri="+REDIRECT_URI));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Then, after the authentication, the access_token is supposed to be returned to me as a parameter to the redirect_url,
but how can my android-app get the url from the system web browser? Also, what should I set to the redirect_url (`http://localhost` would be ok)?

If anyone knows a link with a sample project or code, I would really appreciate it,
because I am new to OAuth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to Choosing a Redirect URI in - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp